# How to extend outer class when using JFrame in NetBeans?

Tags: java, swing, class, inheritance, netbeans

So I am using the NetBeans IDE in order to create a user interface.

My problem is the following:

My JFrame GUI code example (generated by NetBeans)

```
public class AdminGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
...
}
```

and I have an outer class where I create an object based on my input in the GUI

```
public class Foo {
...
}
```

I am trying to have my AdminGUI class to extend Foo and still be able to use the JFrame generated by the NetBeans IDE.

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: sounds very abstract, but you could write: 
`public class AdminGUI extends Foo {`

and

`public class Foo extends javax.swing.JFrame {`

Comment: The general answer is, don't. Have you AdminGUI fill the properties of an instance of Foo instead